# Microsoft Graph API Microsoft Login

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, skypedeveloper

I'm trying to login into a Skype account from windows application. I'm able to sign-in into the Microsoft account using Graph API(https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me) but in response, I'm unable to get skype name and the other data.

I'm able to login into Microsoft account from windows form application following the steps in below URL.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-windows-desktop

I need to know how I can obtain skype name at login using Graph API.Even the Graph API explorer doesn't contain any info regarding skype handle.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Answer (score 0):

The Skype api doesn't use the graph api. Instead it has its own endpoint https://webdirX.online.lync.com.

To get a valid access token you have to send a request with the following format:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/oauth2/authorize?
response_type=id_token
&client_id=<your-application's-client-id>
&redirect_uri=<reply-uri-for-your-app>
&state=<unique-string-to-track-requests>
&resource=webdirX.online.lync.com 
HTTP/1.1
```

For a introduction on how to use it you should take a look at the [Skype for Business authentication using Azure AD article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/authenticationusingazuread).

Comment: thank you  @Oliver for your reply. I'm getting 404 error when sending the above request. Could you guide how can we obtain skype name from email? What API request do we need to make in order to achieve that?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Till now I only used the graph API and never got in touch with the Skype API. After reading your question I knew that you couldn't achieve your goal with the graph API and after some search I found the above article about how to use skype but I never used it. Sorry.